# How can I insert a position of a list in another list in python?

Tags: python, list, insert

I have three lists in python. I want to insert in the last one in the parameter of the position the value of the first and in the parameter of value the value of the second one. This is my code:

```
list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 5, 7, 8]
list2 = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list3 = [0]*len(list1)
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list3.insert(list1[i],list2[i])
```

With this I obtain list3 with a length of 20, not 10 and list3 has to be like this:
[0,1,2,2,2,3,2,4,5,2]. How can I solve this??

Comment: I think you meant to write: `list3[list1[i]] = list2[i]`

Answer (score 1):

we can use `zip` function to get `list1` and `list2` together:

```
list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 5, 7, 8]
list2 = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list3 = [0]*len(list1)

for index, value in zip(list1, list2):
    list3[index] = value
print(list3)
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2]
```